# How do I find a job that sends a specific email?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, jobs, database-mail, string-searching

I had a job sending an irrelevant email to a group of users.

The title of the email was `Staging -> [AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue`.

When I query the jobs table in the msdb database using the title above, I got no answer:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SELECT    j.job_id,
    s.srvname,
    j.name,
    js.step_id,
    js.command,
    j.enabled
FROM    dbo.sysjobs j
JOIN    dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON    js.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN    master.dbo.sysservers s
    ON    s.srvid = j.originating_server_id
WHERE    js.command LIKE N'%Staging -> [AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue%'
```

Only when I alter my query as below, could I find the bandit job:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SELECT    j.job_id,
    s.srvname,
    j.name,
    js.step_id,
    js.command,
    j.enabled
FROM    dbo.sysjobs j
JOIN    dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON    js.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN    master.dbo.sysservers s
    ON    s.srvid = j.originating_server_id
--WHERE    js.command LIKE N'Staging -> [AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue%'
WHERE    js.command LIKE N'%Staging -> %'
```

This is what was the command on the jobstep:

```
if exists (
select count(1) as total
,year(modify_date) as [Year]
,month(modify_date) as [Month]
from repl_aupair r
where r.arrivaldate is not null
and junocore_applicationid not in(
select applicationid from junocore.dbo.replicationUpdateControl
where arrivaldatechanged = 1 )
and modify_Date >='2017-01-26 00:38:46.197'
group by year(modify_date),month(modify_date)
having year(modify_date) >= 2017
--order by [Year] desc
)
begin
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'DBA',
            @recipients = 'my_emails@mycompany.com',
            @body = 'APIA_Repl_Sub.dbo.repl_aupair arrivalDate not null and replicationUpdateControl arrivalDateChanged still 0',
            @subject = 'Staging -> [AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue ';
end
```

Why did my first query not work?

#### Conclusion:

I modified my script and the following two versions work!

After the answer by [EzLo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/147776/ezlo):

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SELECT  j.job_id,
    s.srvname,
    j.name,
    js.step_id,
    js.command,
    j.enabled
FROM    dbo.sysjobs j
JOIN    dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON  js.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN    master.dbo.sysservers s
    ON  s.srvid = j.originating_server_id
WHERE js.command  LIKE '%Staging -> \[AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue%' ESCAPE '\'


USE [msdb]
GO
SELECT  j.job_id,
    s.srvname,
    j.name,
    js.step_id,
    js.command,
    j.enabled
FROM    dbo.sysjobs j
JOIN    dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON  js.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN    master.dbo.sysservers s
    ON  s.srvid = j.originating_server_id
WHERE js.command  LIKE '%Staging -> [[]AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue%'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your first query is the use of unescaped brackets with the `LIKE` operator.

When using the `LIKE` operator, there are a few special characters such as brackets that require escaping if you want to look for them. Characters enclosed in brackets will tell the SQL engine to look for a match between any character listed inside (same as regular expressions).

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'ABC'

SELECT 'match!' WHERE @string LIKE '%[CX]%' -- Sting must have a C or an X
-- Result: match!
```

In your case, using `[AUPAIR]` inside the like will only match 1 letter (either `A`, `U`, `P`, `I` or `R`), and not the whole word.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'Staging -> [AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue'

SELECT 'match!' WHERE @string LIKE '%Staging -> [AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue%'
-- Result: (none)
```

This will however match with the following strings (just 1 letter!):

```
'Staging -> A arrivalDate trigger issue'
'Staging -> U arrivalDate trigger issue'
'Staging -> P arrivalDate trigger issue'
'Staging -> I arrivalDate trigger issue'
'Staging -> R arrivalDate trigger issue'
```

To correctly search for brackets, you can use 2 solutions:

- Declare a custom `ESCAPE` character.

  ```
  DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'Staging -> [AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue'

  SELECT 'match!' WHERE @string LIKE '%Staging -> \[AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue%' ESCAPE '\'
  -- Result: match!
  ```
- Enclose the opening bracket with brackets.

  ```
  DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'Staging -> [AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue'

  SELECT 'match!' WHERE @string LIKE '%Staging -> [[]AUPAIR] arrivalDate trigger issue%'
  -- Result: match!
  ```

Please note that there is **no need to escape the closing bracket** since this one will only be interpreted as a `LIKE` special character as long as there is an opening one before it (which won't be if you escaped it).